# Closing the Microsoft Teams task module popup automatically

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are trying out messaging extensions capability in our Microsoft Teams App that has a command which fetch dynamic set of parameters from the bot when invoked from the compose box.

When the user clicks the messaging extension our app receives payload type 'invoke' and name as 'composeExtension/fetchTask'

Our app process the data and in return it responds with a Adaptive card in task with 'type':'continue' and the Adaptive card is having a link to open URL as below

```
     "task": {
                "type": "continue",
                "value": {
                    "card": {
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                        "content": {
                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                            "version": "1.2",
                            "body": [{
                                    "type": "ActionSet",
                                    "actions": [{
                                        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                        "title": "Open Facebook",
                                        "url": <URL to open Facebook>
                                    }],
                                }

                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

MSTeams shows this card in a task module popup window. When the User click the Action button it open the Facebook page in a new browser tab but the task module popup window is not closed.

Is there anyway to close the task module popup window when the user clicks the Action button ?

Note : We are not using Bot Framework SDK and Microsoft Teams Javascript client SDK.

Comment: Your bot will receive an action saying composeExtension/SubmitAction. You can return 200 OK response there Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, taskEnvelope);

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Bot is not receiving the action composeExtension/SubmitAction with actions.type: Action.OpenUrl .

If we use actions.type: Action.Submit the Bot receives the event composeExtension/SubmitAction. But the URL is not opening in a new page.

Please provide addition instructions to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you look at this sample code for [teams message extension action](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.cs)?

Comment: Gone through the sample code and tried out but that is not helping to resolve the issue. The sample code uses the messaging extension that has static list of parameters. As mentioned our app is not receiving  the action composeExtension/SubmitAction with actions.type: Action.OpenUrl. 

Could you please provide solution for this particular scenario as we cannot switch to static list of parameters ?

Comment: Action type should be submit to get submitAction trigger

Comment: @KumarTech Did you get any solution for this? I am also stuck here.

Comment: @SAI Not yet. Only way to close the Popup is to have the Action type as Submit stated by Trinetra-MSFT. When User clicks on the Action.openUrl no actions are submitted to App to close the popup.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do two things on one user action is by using a web based task module.

Do some simple layout with a button. In the click handler use window.open(, "_blank") and when that completes call the microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(...) method of the javascript SDK.

Answer (score 0):

this might be late.

But the documentation is wrong try to call the `submitTask(data)` twice once with data and once without any params `submitTask()` to close the taskmodule.